# Linux shared library dependency resolution

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, shared-libraries

Scenario:

```
python   --> python-openssl --> libssl.so.1.0.1 --> libcrypto.so.1.0.1
myapp.py --> myExt.so  --> XXXlib.so --> libssl.so.0.9.8 --> libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Above dependencies are verified via `ldd`.

When I executed `python myapp.py`

1. On Ubuntu 12.04.4 (gcc 4.6.3)

   The program was ended with segfault and backtrace revealed the libssl.so`.0.9.8` invoked a function from libcrypto.so`.1.0.1`.
2. On Ubuntu 14.04 (gcc 4.8.x)

   The program behaved normal.

So far my workaround for the issue on Ubuntu 12.04 is manually compiling python from source and forcing it link with openssl-0.9.8.

Why the resolution works correctly on Ubuntu 14.04? And, can it apply to 12.04?

Comment: you're more likely to get help from people that have experienced the same problem by adding a `python` tag to your question. Good luck.

Comment: 1. Sheer luck. 2. Dont bother to even think of maybe trying it some day. Linking with two different versions of the same library is Just Plain Wrong and it will break when you are expecting it the least. 3. Using a product that is not regularly updated to the latest openssl is problematic, double check you really want it.

Comment: @n.m. Can't agree with you more. I have no choice but the XXXlib though.

Comment: Sorry, but I think `n.m.` has a pretty good handle on this. Best to regroup and find an appropirate solution.